# Ideas or options for a door in an open stairway

Tags: doors, sound-proofing

I found a [semi-related post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/184406/barn-door-with-no-header) about this, but it doesn't really answer my question. It basically claims a horizontal, wall-mounted barn door could work in a space like below (see images). However, all horizontal, wall-mounted barn doors I have found seem to need to connect to the wall above the door when closed to keep it supported.

In my case, there is no wall above the opening above the door. The options I am considering:

- Add some sort of supporting wood board that connects to the wall on each side of the opening, then allows for a horizontal barn door to be connected to above the door when it's closed. The con to this is it will not look great.
- I have also researched and found some ceiling hanging barn door options. This seems like a great option, however, I don't know if there are any drawbacks to hanging a door to the ceiling. I have never attempted anything like that. I am not sure what to consider there.

[image][image][image]

My question is: **Are there any other solutions or ideas I could or should consider for this space?**

**The goal here is to stop sound from traveling up the stairwell, as it currently does**. Maybe there is a door type or covering I am not aware of that would work just as easily.

Comment: What type of sound deading do you need?  Do you have have DIY skills or want/need a brought/commercial option?  Heavy drapes might be one idea.  A self built hinged door is another.

Comment: It's that glass. It's a mirror for sound. And a window for heat.  Heavy draperies would help.

Comment: Would you leave this stairwell door closed most of the time?  Or open and only close it when the kids are trying to sleep upstairs ?

Comment: @Criggie It would remain open most of the time. It's mainly been an issue when our sons have sleepovers and they are fairly loud downstairs and people upstairs are trying to sleep :)

Comment: @Shane I suggest an agreed time where things quieten down, a consequence for being too loud after ~2300, and earplugs for those upstairs :)   And remember if they're noisy at night, you can be noisy first thing in the morning... payback !

Comment: Since this was closed, I'm going to suggest a white noise machine in the bedrooms. A white noise machine in the bedroom drowns out almost any noise from outside the room. Or, you could use a smart devices to play something like ocean sounds or rain. My nightly routine is "Alexa, play thunderstorms" at like volume 3; works like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with a door here is that it will feel weird and cramped to people coming down the stairs.  So you need enough space on the flat-floor to stand and open the door.  Right now it looks about one stair-tread of depth, ideally you'd want triple that.

I would suggest a curtain rail over the access, and hang a sound-absorbing curtain made from velvet or wool.  You'd want a bi-pane curtain not a single-sided one, so that it opens from the center like a tent.

There should be room beside so the open curtain does not narrow the width at all, so curtain would hang on the nearside of the wall, not in-line with the wall.

Additionally, can anything be done at the top-end of the stairs?

Anything that lowers the lintel will cause issues for people walking down the stairs.  Don't make your house suitable only for short people.  It already looks close to the forehead of stair-users.

---

Your stairs are hard bare wood - that is an excellent sound reflector.  Consider carpetting both the tread and the riser, and the landing.   This will also reduce damage in the event of a fall.

There's probably not a lot you can do for the walls.  Some paints have noise-absorbing properties but its not great.  Music studios minimise reflection with fabric/foam panels, but that takes depth and stairwells aren't that wide.  Adding some framed unglazed pictures might help.

Lastly, your window is also a hard flat surface that reflects sound like a mirror reflects light.  Temporarily hang a sheet or blanket on it and see if it makes a perceptible difference.  If so, consider a curtain there.  If light is required, consider a lightweight net curtain in the alcove to fuzz and disrupt sound while adding privacy.

Comment: I hate, detest, and abhor curtains across doorways. I'm sure I'm not alone in this.

Comment: @Martha fair enough.   OP says its only for occasional usage, not everyday, and the main advantage is the minimal floor space taken.  A swinging-open door has to have clear space to open and a curtain needs far less space.

Comment: **All landings are to be three feet deep.** "ideally" has nothing to do with it. *The Code is law.*

Answer (score 6):

A few options come to mind:

- A common swinging door. Easy to frame there.
- A barn door, sliding right. Sliding left is probably prohibited and likely impractical because of the other door.
- A pocket door in a faux wall on the right

Additionally, or in lieu of the above, pad the stairs with carpet, pad the walls with decorative carpets, add (faux) curtain to the stairway window.

I prefer a swinging door because they generally seal better when closed and make no noise when operated. A pocket door comes second. Barn doors still pass lots of noise.

Barn or sliding door rail sound will transfer via rail, header and framing to upstairs.

Closing the opening to fit a door, or installing a header to fit a rail should be no problem.

Consider a glass-panelled or all-glass door for aesthetics and light. Plus the improved visibility helps prevent traffic conflicts.

If you have framing questions after your decision, let us know.

It is advisable to check the local building code, and also check the practicality of any kind of door or curtain at the bottom of stairs, e.g. handle reach from stairs etc... But at first glance it looks like you have sufficient landing before the door, so this might not be a practical issue.

Comment: Glass options were not something we considered, but now like the idea of! Thanks for the tip! This is all suuuuuper helpful.

Comment: I'd be quite concerned about a glass door in this location. It's *very* unusual to have a door in such a location with so little space between the bottom stair and where the door must be. In normal use, with a glass door there, it would be *very* easy to not notice/remember that the door is there and closed. Thus, it would be substantially more likely to just try to walk through the closed glass door. For accidents, if someone takes a tumble down those stairs and the glass door is closed, then they are certain to hit it and likely to break it. That could change an "ouch" to a "you're dead".

Comment: @Makyen glass doors are made of safety glass and aren't easily broken. OP can build a landing box if space permits. OP must check local building code.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an accordion door (note: the accordion will not contribute to noise).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option could be free-swinging **French doors**; while ideally you want more space between the bottom step and the door than you've got, French doors wouldn't feel like as much of an obstacle. Obviously, they would need to swing out into the room, away from the stairs.

However, if the goal is to *reduce* noise, a better solution might be **sound baffles**. Empty stairs like that tend to collect and amplify noise; since there is nothing to absorb the sound inside, it bounces right back out just as loud as when it started. While there's not a lot you can do about the large window, the walls to the left and right could be draped with soft blankets or tapestries, or fitted with acoustic panels. You may even be able to fit the area over the stairs with something. Obviously, you could combine those with a door for even better sound-proofing.